# Does rebuilding a computer game from scratch infringe copyright?

Tags: copyright

A game named Blinx, was manufactured last in 2004 by a company named Microsoft. In 2014-2015 they dropped the trademark, and so the name is usable, but the game, the intellectual material is copyrighted. If I don't use their images or their code, can I legally reproduce the game?

Comment: Not an answer, but an example of this being done is [OpenTTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenTTD), a complete remake of Transport Tycoon Deluxe, with new graphics and sounds, but (at least early on) the same gameplay/logic.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to "*make a game with the same game rules and logic, but with new code & new graphics*", then yes, you can.

Copyright protects an expression of an idea, but not the idea itself. In the context of game development, an *idea* can be tic-tac-toe game. I write a webpage with JavaScript to play the game, that is my *expression*. You cannot reproduce my webpage without my consent, but you are free to code an exact replica of the game say, in iOS.

To prevent someone from making a game with the exact (or very similar) rules, you'd need a patent. Two famous games which are patented are "[Monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game))" (they got the name right!) and [Tetris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris)*. There is a reason why you see people making many Reversi, Sudoku, Tic-Tac-Toe etc implementations in the app store, but not Monopoly and Tetris.

<sub>*Technically, Tetris is not protected by patent, only by copyright. Many developers have [rejected the company's copyright infringement claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tetris_Company) as game design is not covered by copyright.</sub>

Comment: IMO the question calls for some analysis of "look and feel" case law.

Comment: Fun fact: any patents on Tetris or Monopoly will have expired by now.